# imported .obj shows too small

Tags: python, import, scale

Yesterday it was working fine and today it is not

I imported my obj file and it is not showing up or it is too small I guess but I can see it on outliner.

[image: this is the picture]

Comment: Did you try to scale it..?

Comment: nothing happen when I scale it still small

Comment: There is nothing apart the origin of the object in the imported file (you can see by the total number of vertices of the scene: 0 verts, 0 edges, 0 faces). Did you try to open the file with another app? Are you sure it was coorctly exported?

Answer (score 1):

It could also be way to big, try hitting the . key on the number pad and see where it takes you, if it's to big, scale it down. It also helps to set the origin to "centre of mass" or "geometry" and resetting its location with alt+g.

Comment: Thanks but it is way to small . key take me zoom in to the orange dot.

Answer (score 0):

Your question provides very little information, so it's just guesswork here. I assume you exported your OBJ again. Check your export settings, especially the unit setting in your export programm. Try setting blender to the same unit used as in your export (under 'scene properties').