# My imported .obj model is appearing as a tiny dot

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, objects, export

I wanted to extract some models from ps2 games to blender. I followed this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHlJ3qO4lys and got through all the steps, extracted my model exactly as shown and received an .obj file.

I opened the file in Blender and all I could see was a tiny dot instead of my model. I attempted scaling, moving and pretty much everything I could think of to make my model appear. I looked all over the internet and could not find anything.

Another thing I thought of was that the tutorial used 3ds max, but I saw others in the comments saying they used blender too. I don't think it's a problem with the game I am extracting from (DBZ budokai tenkaichi 3) ;tldr: I followed a video and extracted a ps2 model to Blender but all I received was a tiny dot.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I looked at the other questions and still cannot make it work. I have attached the model's file, maybe somebody could take a look and see if they can figure it out for me. [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88007/imported-obj-shows-too-small

Comment: The file you uploades has nothing. Zero vertices, Zero Faces, Zero Tris... Whatever you did to create that object didn't work....

Comment: I watched the video again and realized I made an error extracting the model. I got it fixed now though, thanks for your help.